# Replace for varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to replace var binary,but I'm unsuccessful.

My update statement is:

```
update Test 
set Sect_ID = cast(replace(Sect_ID, '2', '3') as varbinary);
```

It's not replacing anything. It's still the same old value.

Answer (score 0):

If `Sect_ID` is a `varbinary(max)` column, did you try casting it to `varchar(max)` inside the `REPLACE()` function call?

With this sample schema, things seemed to work for me:

```
CREATE TABLE Foo (Bar varbinary(max))

INSERT INTO Foo (Bar) 
VALUES (CAST('1234' AS varbinary(MAX)))
```

Now run this and you'll see the value get updated as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Foo

UPDATE Foo
SET Bar = CAST(REPLACE(CAST(Bar AS varchar(MAX)), '2', '5') AS varbinary(MAX));

SELECT * 
FROM Foo
```