# Replace random varbinary data in middle of column (MSSQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a **inventory** column with various data and multiple rows, it's necessary replace random *varbinary* data in middle of column.

Example of Inventory column:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLjHh.png)

For example this:

```
0x0500420000000000005000FFFFFFFFFF56730E64FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0400180000000000006000FFFFFFFFFF56730E72FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF04001E0000000000007000FFFFFFFFFF56730E5EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

Need to be changed to:

```
0x0500420000000000005000FFFFFFFFFF56730E64FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF04001E0000000000007000FFFFFFFFFF56730E5EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
```

I know how to change static data like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28749683/replace-for-varbinary). But here is many rows and in every row data is different. It's possible maybe change data somehow by length? Start length position is 67, end 131.

Comment: When you say "random" do you really mean "variable" or do you actually want a section updated randomly?

Comment: I mean variable data in middle of column need to be changed to static data 'FF'.

Comment: And do you have a table that specifies Row with Id X should have start position 67 until end 131 masked out or where will this come from?

Comment: It's column length position, screenshot: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/74927c714367e27ed434d08e5ab8a8ec.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But here is many rows and in every row data is different. It's possible maybe change data somehow by length? Start length position is 67, end 131.

You can use `STUFF` or `SUBSTRING` and `+` to rewrite the entire blob, or you can update it in-place,  see [Updating Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#updating-lobs), eg

```
drop table if exists #temp
go
create table #temp(id int, blob varbinary(max))
insert into #temp(id,blob) values (1,0x0500420000000000005000FFFFFFFFFF56730E64FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0400180000000000006000FFFFFFFFFF56730E72FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF04001E0000000000007000FFFFFFFFFF56730E5EFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF)

declare @newBytes varbinary(100) = 0xAAAAAAAAAAAA

--only for varbinary(max) but updates in-place
update #temp 
  set blob.write(@newBytes,10,datalength(@newBytes))

--for varbinary(max) or varbinary(n) replace the whole value
update #temp 
  set blob = cast(STUFF(blob,30,datalength(@newBytes),@newBytes) as varbinary(max))

select * from #temp
```

Comment: This is what can resolve issue, with blob column working fine, but with inventory column i receive error msg: "Cannot call methods on varbinary." Seems it's because i have varbinary length limit in column properties. How to solve this?

Comment: See updated answer.